# When to write a long stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures

Are there any guidelines on when you should and should not write a long complicated 2000+ line stored procedure?

In my specific case this stored procedure contains a lot of if/then, case, goto and branching statements.  It works by constructing SQL queries depending on inputs and results of queries and uses the execute statement to run the constructed queries.  It can execute several constructed queries in one call and uses results of those queries to construct other queries to run.

It is pretty messy and hard to understand.  Debugging is tough, the only way to know what is going on is to step through a call to see what it's doing.  There barely any exception handling or logging.  Maintaining it is a pain.  In fact, no one really knows what it does or how it was created and if we had to make modifications to it we would have to take a "cross your fingers and hope for the best" approach.  But, I think it was done this way for performance reasons.

This procedure is used by many applications.  The only other way I can think to do something like this is through a web service.  It would probably be comparable in complexity, but a lot easier to understand.  However, it would probably be multiple times slower as it would still have to make several calls to the database for 1 request.

So, my question(s) are, how do we decide when and when not to write long stored procedures?

Is there something I'm missing or do we just have to put up with our monstrous stored procedure?

Are there ways to structure and break down stored procedures into smaller components so they are easy to understand?

Will a stored procedure always be faster than anything else and the right choice when you need to make many calls to the database?

Comment: One word: **NEVER!**  You should never write such a monstrosity.... any function/procedure should be no more than two pages long - and that's taking a very liberal stand on this matter.... 150 lines - MAX. 2000 lines of code in a single procedure .... - what a maintenance nightmare!

Comment: @dtc - hey, was wondering if/how you resolved the huge proc issue. I feel your pain. I have a 1550 LOC proc that I have a handle on now but early on, it was a beast to learn/figure out. Am wondering myself how this could/should be broken up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure that it's ever a good idea to write 2000+ LOC for a single function. My initial reaction is to say that your sproc should be broken up into smaller functions (table-valued or scalar, whatever is appropriate) and stored procedures (for non-query operations). However, that might just be moving the LOC around rather than simplifying the actual operation. Unfortunately, without any source code posted it'd be difficult to give more specific advice.

Comment: Thank you, this is the type of comment I was hoping for.  Posting 2000+ lines might be a bit much and I doubt my company would appreciate me posting any part of the code.  I can see how using views or functions would help, but problem is it dynamically creates queries based on results of other queries.  That might turn out to be a lot of sprocs, views and fuctions we have to make.

Answer (score 7):

Sounds like you need to change the way you write and maintain this stored procedure.

A stored procedure is created from a SQL query.  Maybe you can write an application/script to generate the SQL to create/update your stored procedure.

Doing this would give you all the benefits of a re-usable stored procedure (the benefits you already have), but it would make maintenance of the stored procedure easier.

By having a 2000+ line stored procedure, you are basically locking yourself in as the only person who can do the job.  This means you are stuck where you are and cannot move forward (no job promotion, no assignment to a new project, etc).

Answer (score 0):

If you still have this problem, you may try now to use some CLR (Common Language Runtime Integration) which is using some other microsoft language as C#, visual basic, among others to code your solution. This will help with the debuggin and maintennace of your code.